# I have changed my swift viewController name and all my ui members are nil now

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `Main.storyboard` which was defaultly connected to UiViewController named `ViewController`

I have changed the name of the UiViewController to `InlineMainViewController` and all the sudden the UI members are all nil
while I debug the `override func viewDidLoad() {`

I have set the new connection via the storyboard editor. see:

[editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkw2I.png)

[project navigator and ui elements radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kyHI.png)

how can I fix this?

**Update**

found the problem:

I added:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

mainViewController = InlineMainViewController()
}
```

this bypass natural and healthy initialization?

Comment: is "InlineMainViewController" available in your bundle ?

Comment: upload the pic of "Project Navigator also" ?

Comment: Reconnect all UI member of `InlineMainViewController`.

Comment: @sanjeet how do I check if "InlineMainViewController" available in my bundle?
I just changed its name not location or new file

Comment: @technerd but i see they are connected even ow (check radio button)

Comment: if you want to give a name to  your view controller use Storyboard ID field and if you want to assign new viewController class create new view controller and assign it in class field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating whole new object of InlineViewController using `InlineViewController()`.So it is not using ViewController from Storyboard in which you have bind UI component.

So, try to create viewController object from Storyboard.
Add ViewController identifier to your view controller and use it in place of `ViewController_Identifier` in given code.

Try below code.

```
  let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  mainViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController_Identifier")
```

This code create object of InitialViewController which you crated in storyboard. So you will get all UI component.